# How to get system locale in Android 13+ even when it is not listed in the app's `resourceConfigurations`

Tags: android, localization, location, locale

I need to know what locale a user is located in for legal reasons. We've settled on using the users' system locale as the way to get the users' locations. The problem I have is that with Android 13+ per-app locale, if a user's system is set to a local that is not list in my app's `resourceConfigurations` then `Locale.getDefault()` will return a locale that is listed in `resourceConfigurations` even if the user has not explicitly set a different per-app locale from the system locale.

I need a way to see the system locale regardless of the locale the system has set for my app.

If I remove `resourceConfigurations` from the app's `build.gradle` then the problem I'm having is fixed, however, then the system (understandably) doesn't show the correct languages in the system per-app language picker.

`Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale` and `Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)` both return the same as `Locale.getDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know for legal reasons, do NOT use locale.  It has no relationship to the place the user is in or the laws they follow.  It relates to their preferred language.  For example a US ex-pat living in Europe will still have their phone set to en.  You don't even know if it will be set to en-us, or en-uk because they bought it in europe and that's the default for en on that model.  It's not going to be right enough to use for anything that needs to be done for legal purposes.

Comment: @CodeDroid If you're still trying to do it, then no they haven't been considered.  The locale is not the legal juridstiction of the phone.  It doesn't even try to be, that's not what it's for.  If you really have legal concerns about getting where they are, then you're just setting yourself up for lawsuits by even attempting to do this.  And you're failing your duty as an engineer by not pushing back harder.